# Converting to factor leads to NA

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in `R`.

```
data<-data.frame(Outlook=c("Sunny","Sunny","Overcast","Rainy","Rainy","Rainy",    "Overcast", "Sunny") )
```

but i need to change it to assign an integer to each value (make it `factor`). So, i run:

```
ordered(as.character(data$Outlook),
levels = c(100,50, 30),
labels = c("Overcast", "Rainy", "Sunny"))
```

But it makes all `NA` for me

```
<NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
Levels: Overcast < Rainy < Sunny
```

So, **how can i stop it from making NAs?**

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information), but didn't help me

Comment: The levels should respond to unique values you see in your data (and potentially more values)

Comment: I don't think we need factor, maybe use lookup? `data$OutlookN <- setNames(c(100, 50, 30), c("Overcast", "Rainy", "Sunny"))[data$Outlook]`

Comment: If you really want an ordered factor, `ordered(data$Outlook)` or `ordered(data$Outlook, levels=rev(levels(data$Outlook)))` will work with reversed orders.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the @zx8754

```
outlook<-setNames(c(100, 50, 30), c("Overcast", "Rainy", "Sunny"))[data$Outlook]
```

solved the problem

Comment: Click on edit, then you will see a tiny checkbox on the right bottom.

Comment: I will make it, but what about this case `setNames(c(100, 50), c(TRUE,FALSE))[data$Windy]`

Comment: Anyway, my comment about wiki was simply - "avoid copy pasting my comment as your own answer".

Comment: @zx8754 if u don't like it, i can remove it, and i will accept ur answer, but u didn't write any answer, and i think, it is more readable for other people if they see an answer

Comment: I used comment to clarify the expected output, as you were asking about factors, and I suggested using lookups. It is OK and encouraged to convert comments to answers, but not as fast :) Keep as it is, expand with the final solution. I don't mind.